# How to specify mark to split words if there are repeat same marks in a cell in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I used the split formula and took the "hyphen mark" `-` to split two team names as FC Tokyo-Cerezo Osaka (`F1:G1` is correct). But some team names include `-` for example, Shimizu S-Pulse-Cerezo Osaka which will split over two cells, or sometimes there are two teams including `-` for example Paris Saint-Germain F.C.-Shimizu S-Pulse. I have used the `REGEXREPLACE` formula to try to replace the team name including `-`, however, the match schedule is random which team names are not fixed in the same place. Please someone help, thank you very much.

Example picture： https://i.stack.imgur.com/23gjj.jpg

Comment: Do you have a database of all available teams? That you could lookup and check if any of the team names exists or not?

Comment: Nope, I google match schedule and use the copy and paste "team name - team name" in google sheet.

Comment: The team names cannot be logically separated from the "team-team" if any team can have a `-` in it. There is no way to decide what is a full team name without a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula in F1:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(D:D="",,QUERY(IF(LEN(REGEXREPLACE(D:D,"[^-]",""))=1,SPLIT(D:D,"-"),IF(LEN(REGEXREPLACE(D:D,"[^-]",""))=2,IF(((NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(D:D,"^[^-]+")&"*",D:D,1,FALSE))))*(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(D:D,"-(.+)$")&"*",D:D,1,FALSE))))) + ((NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP("*"&REGEXEXTRACT(D:D,"^[^-]+"),D:D,1,FALSE))))*(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP("*"&REGEXEXTRACT(D:D,"-(.+)$"),D:D,1,FALSE))))),SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(D:D,"-","|",1),"|"),SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(D:D,"-","|",2),"|")),SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(D:D,"-","|",2),"|"))),"Select Col1, Col2",0)))`

I trust you'll understand why I can't explain here in full how the formula works. But basically, it treats three different cases differently:

1.) If there is only a single hyphen, `SPLIT` at that hyphen.

2.) If there are two hyphens, `SPLIT` at the first hyphen `IF` doing so would allow you to locate *both* elements of the `SPLIT` in their entirety either at the very beginning or the very end of any string anywhere within the original list; otherwise, `SPLIT` at the second hyphen.

3.) If there are three hyphens, locate and `SPLIT` at the center hyphen.

It may not behave flawlessly with a larger data set. But it holds up using your sample data set.

Comment: I have tried to use this formula to split about 700 columns of "Team-Team" and it is still working, I appreciate and admire your solution, thank you very much.

Comment: Good to know. Glad it's working out in real application. Thanks for reporting back.